# Docker - AWS - What do I need to do next?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, web-applications, amazon-ec2, putty

I'm totally new at AWS and also Docker, but I figured out how to create an instance with AWS and how to install docker on it and pull/run a docker image. Right now, I'm running on my AWS-Instance two images, dla-core and dla-gui.

When I was running it on my local docker quickstart terminal, I could check my web application on IP 192.168.99.100. But now I need to get it to a domain.com and I have no idea what to do next. Do you have any idea, time (maybe for TeamViewer) and motivation to help a desperate student who need's to run this application today on a domain? Thank you very much, comments and responds are also very appreciated!

[image]

Here is my **Dockerfile for core** (backend):

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-8

# Build
ADD . /sketchpass-core
ADD src/main/bash/run.sh /sketchpass-core/
WORKDIR /sketchpass-core
RUN mvn clean install
RUN chmod +x run.sh

# Run
EXPOSE 11337
ENV SKETCHPASS_CONFIG=conf/defaults.properties
CMD ["/sketchpass-core/run.sh"]
```

and that's the **Dockerfile of gui** (front-end)

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python-requests python-flask python-pandas python-pil gunicorn

ADD . /
CMD ["python", "scribble.py"]

EXPOSE 80
```

first I'm starting build_core.sh

```
#/bin/bash
#mvn clean install
#JAR_WITH_DEPENDENCIES=`find target/dla-core*.jar -printf "%f"`
docker build --tag profile/dla-core .
```

followed by run_core.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
SKETCHPASS_CONFIG="conf/defaults.properties"
docker rm -f dla-core
docker run --name dla-core profile/dla-core
```

and afterwards I was moving to gui:
build_gui.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
docker build -t profile/dla-gui .
```

run_gui.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
docker rm -f dla-gui
docker run --name dla-gui --rm -t -p 80:80 -v `pwd`:/dla-gui -e "SKETCHPASS_DEBUG=true" --link dla-core:backend profile/dla-gui
```

Comment: To remove all containers: `docker rm -v $(docker ps -aq)`

Comment: That looks good. Which error do you encounter? Can your frontend access your backend?

Comment: yes, if I run everything as I used to run with Docker Toolbox Terminal, everything works fine. I could see my application on http://192.168.99.100/

I pushed both repos to pull it from my AWS-EC2-Instance. It worked, I can pull it and I can run the images. But I can't access to it on my elastic ip/dns. And that's my problem, I need to make my web application accessible.

Comment: You can use `docker logs <container_name>` to display logs/errors.

Comment: I figured it out, it's running now! Thank you very very much Celine!
Whereever you are, assume that you will receive flowers from me! Thank you very much again :-) happy christmas!

Comment: :-D You’re welcome Faruk! Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 2):

To run your docker container on port 80: `docker run -d -p 80:80 <docker_image> <command>`. If you don't specify the `<command>`, it will use the default command that's defined in the docker image. Docker documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

You can then display your container running `docker ps` and you can display the logs running `docker logs <container_name>`

To make it externally accessible, you need to edit your instance Security Group and open the port of your app (port 80 based on your screenshot) to 0.0.0.0/0 if you want it to be accessible from anywhere. 
At this point you should be able to access your website using the instance Public IP.

Then you need to add your instance Public IP to a A record in your DNS.

Comment: Hi Celine! I posted a screenshot of my security group, did I set something wrong? I can't access my application using the instance public IP.

Comment: Then you need to make sure the app is running on that port on your instance. Did you launch your Docker container with something like this: `-p 80:80`?

Comment: No I just said sudo docker run -it myprofile/dla-core and same for dla-gui. Should I add also -p 80:80 at the end?

Comment: That's interactive mode, that won't work. Try `docker run -d -p 80:80 myprofile/dla-core` I'll update the answer with more details.

Comment: Thank you very much Celine! But right now the terminal says:





Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint cocky_swirles (f4a8eca1adc562bbdb9751fa916da9dde8f572c60742731be1f2ba625ebffba2): Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated.'

Comment: hmm yes, both containers can't run on the same instance port. You should publish the port (`-p 80:80`) only for the application that needs to be accessible externally. Then I don't know how your system works... Do the 2 applications communicate between each others?

Comment: Yes they do, the backend (in this case core) is basically java which calculates the entries of front-end (in this case gui) and returns true or false. And the front-end, gui is a festival of python, flask, javascript, html-templates etc.

Comment: OK, to which address was the gui accessing the backend on your localhost? There are several ways to connect them. You can use Docker links for example. `docker run -d --name backend myprofile/dla-core` and `docker run -d -p 80:80 --link backend:backend myprofile/dla-gui`. Then your backend will be accessible at `backend:<core_port>` inside the dla-gui container. I'm not sure how you manage your configuration... You can pass environment variables using the `-e` option.

Comment: I updated again my question with a picture. Thank you by the way celine for taking time to respond me. Well I was running it with sh. I'm updating my question again with the shell-scripts.

Comment: @FarukDoganci  Post your dockerfile or docker-compose file, so that, we can understand about your container links

Comment: @LakshmanDiwaakar Thank you very much for your comment, I updated my question with both Dockerfiles.

Comment: I think the docker files are correct!! So can you access your web app on 80 port in localhost ? Do you need a public Ip?

Comment: exactly I need a public IP, which I have on AWS (elastic IP)

Answer (score 0):

1)Run your docker container with Host port bind to 80.

2) Allow port 80 in Security group assigned to that EC2 instance.

3) Map Public ip to A record in AWS Route53